# Text_field not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an open-source spreadsheet application. So far, its a rails application that has 4 models: table, row, column, and item.

Here is what they look like:

Table.rb:

```
has_many :columns
has_many :rows
accepts_nested_attributes_for :columns
```

Column.rb

```
belongs_to :table
has_many :items
```

Row.rb

```
belongs_to :table
has_many :items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
```

Item.rb

```
belongs_to :row
```

On the page where you add a new row. You should be presented with something like this:

[image]

So the columns are already set, so now you are adding new *items* which when inserted should include the **row_id**, **column_id**, and **value** for each item.

So far my form looks like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for [@table, @row] do |f| %>

 <% @columns.each do |column| %>
    <%= column.name %> <br>
    <%= f.fields_for :items do |item_form| %>
       <%= item_form.text_field :value %>
    <% end %>

 <% end%>

 <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

I'm using the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for the nested forms. But so far, I can't get a textbox for the item's value to show up. Also, is this the best way to get what I want (like the picture), or is there a cleaner way?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: I'm not sure modeling columns and rows is the best way to go about this. Why not have a model for Cell, with each cell having a row and column attribute? Rows and columns don't need to be represented in the database, they are just meta-data for the cells...Your schema is going to result in a lot of excess DB calls. Just my $0.02 and if you have some specific functionality in mind that needs those models, feel free to ignore...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build at least 1 item for fields_for to render anything. Try doing this in your `new` controller action.

```
def new
  ...
  @row.items.build
end
```